# Bootstrap Horizontal Line start at Left: 0; & Img-Responsive not working on Fixed Image

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've got a responsive HR line in a client's webpage but I need to make it so that  the HR STARTS at Col-md-1, and finish at approximately col-md-6. I keeps (despite technically occupying Col-md-1 to 6) misses a small gap on the left hand side.

The problem being, due to my lack of knowledge of Bootstrap, I'm unsure on how to make this happen.

Heres the HTML:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2 col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1">
            <hr class="bigHR1">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
.bigHR1 {
    background-color: white !important;
    color: white !important;
    border: 2px solid white !important;
    border-radius: 50%;
    height: 1px !important;
    width: auto !important;
}
```

[image: I've circled the gap I need to vanish in this screenshot]

---

I've been able to make my image fixed and have used TOP & LEFT 0 to keep it in a certain place. Within Bootstrap, the image will display on LG, MD and SM sided windows, but vanish on XS windows.

The location of the image is perfect, but I want the image to scale appropriately for the size of the screen (i.e Be responsive). But I want the aspect ratio to remain the same, and for the image to NOT move.

Heres the HTML so far:

```
<!-- PICTURE -->
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="img-responsive col-sm-2 hidden-xs">
        <div class="BackgroundImage"><img src="Pictures/Profile.png" alt="Background Image"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Heres the CSS:

```
.BackgroundImage img {
    z-index: -1;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right:0;
}
```

Heres where it positions on the page, and how I want the aspect ratio to stay the same (Top of head inline with the top bar of the page etc..

[image: Neil's Picture]